# Solving Maze with Python Stack

Tags: python, stack, maze

```
        counter=0
        east=maze[row][column+1]
        west=maze[row][column-1]
        south=maze[row+1][column]
        north=maze[row-1][column]
        for i in range(0, maze.getHeight()):
            for j in range(0, maze.getHeight()):
                if i!=maze.getHeight() and j!=maze.getWidth():
                    if not south in (BARRIER, VISITED):
                        exploreStack.push((row+1, column))
                        counter+=1
                    elif not north in (BARRIER, VISITED):
                        exploreStack.push((row-1, column))
                        counter+=1

                    if not east in (BARRIER, VISITED):
                        exploreStack.push((row, column+1))
                        counter+=1
                    elif not west in (BARRIER, VISITED):
                        exploreStack.push((row, column-1))
                        counter+=1
```

I'm trying to do this with a loop of some sort. It's completing the maze but it's still giving me an error. I don't know if its the conditionals or its just the indexing. Please help.

This is the error...

File "C:\Documents\MyPython\Programs\solveMaze.py", line 106, in solveMaze east=maze[row][column+1]

IndexError: list index out of range

This is the error I'm getting out of a certain maze looking for it's way out. But it completes other mazes.

Comment: Unless there's an indentation error you `return counter` in the middle of the loop, meaning it will never run a full iteration before you exit the `solveMaze` function. The inner `while` loop should also not be a while loop (you do not appear to be looping over anything there?) and you need to consider the maze edges, right now it looks like you will try to access values outside the maze.

Comment: The condition to your while loop is made with `or` meaning one truthy evaluation will run the loop…

Comment: Can you show the error you are obtaining please?

Comment: The comment has been edited into the post.